# referencing keys oracle, could be foreign key issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

I keep having an issue where I'm trying to load all my tables into a database.

Whenever I try load a table which references "paper_code" I keep getting problem errors, which then don't create the table.

I've been trying to nail out the errors and have got some papers loading, but it seems only the tables that reference papers(paper_code) are having issues.

code:

```
DROP TABLE contacts;
DROP TABLE gender;
DROP TABLE lecture_location;
DROP TABLE enrols;
DROP TABLE teaches;
DROP TABLE staff;
DROP TABLE student;
DROP TABLE papers;
DROP TABLE departments;


CREATE TABLE departments
   (dept_id     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
   dept_location VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
   dept_name     VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO departments VALUES
   (01, 'ALBANY STREET', 'COMPUTER SCIENCE');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES
   (02, 'UNION STREET', 'MUSIC');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES
   (03, 'HOWE STREET', 'ANATOMY');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES
   (04, 'ANZAC AVENUE', 'THEATRE');

CREATE TABLE papers
   (paper_code      INT,
   EFTS             INT     NOT NULL,
   dept_id          INT     REFERENCES departments(dept_id),
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_code, dept_id));


INSERT INTO papers VALUES
   (160, 0.18, 01);
INSERT INTO papers VALUES
   (241, 0.18, 02);
INSERT INTO papers VALUES
   (344, 0.18, 03);
INSERT INTO papers VALUES
   (444, 0.18, 04);

CREATE TABLE student
   (student_id      INT     PRIMARY KEY,
   fname            CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   lname            CHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   degree           CHAR(15) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO student VALUES
   (172384, 'Michael', 'McDonald', 'BSc');
INSERT INTO student VALUES
   (849294, 'Matthew', 'Brockie', 'BA');
INSERT INTO student VALUES
   (384583, 'Daniel', 'Anderson', 'BSc');

CREATE TABLE staff
   (staff_id        INT     PRIMARY KEY,
   dept_id         INT      REFERENCES departments(dept_id),
   fname           CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   lname           CHAR(15) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (31, 01, 'Tony', 'Michaels');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (32, 01, 'Steph', 'Cardy');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (33, 02, 'Alex', 'Freeland');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (34, 02, 'Sam', 'Stewart');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (35, 03, 'Monique', 'Cardy');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES
   (36, 03, 'Bayan', 'Zach');


CREATE TABLE teaches
   (paper_code         INT,
   staff_id         INT      REFERENCES staff(staff_id),
   dept_id          INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_code, staff_id, dept_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (paper_code, dept_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_code, dept_id));

INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (160, 32, 01);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (241, 31, 01);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (344, 33, 02);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (241, 34, 03);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (444, 35, 03);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
   (444, 36, 04);

CREATE TABLE enrols
   (paper_code         INT     REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
   student_id         INT      REFERENCES student(student_id),
   date_enrolled      DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_code, student_id));

INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (160, 172384, TO_DATE('22-Mar-1994', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (444, 849294, TO_DATE('14-Jul-1992', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (444, 172384, TO_DATE('23-Mar-1992', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (160, 384583, TO_DATE('07-Aug-1992', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES --fix
   (160, 172384, TO_DATE('30-Jul-1994', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (241, 849294, TO_DATE('08-Sep-1995', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
INSERT INTO enrols VALUES
   (241, 384583, TO_DATE('25-Dec-1996', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));


CREATE TABLE lecture_location
   (paper_code      INT     REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
   dept_id          INT     REFERENCES departments(dept_id),
   lecture_loc     VARCHAR2(15),
   PRIMARY KEY(paper_code, dept_id, lecture_loc));

INSERT INTO lecture_location VALUES
   (160, 'ARCHWAY');
INSERT INTO lecture_location VALUES
   (241, 'CASTLE');

CREATE TABLE gender
   (student_id      INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES student(student_id),
   gender           CHAR(9) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO gender VALUES
   (172384, 'Female');
INSERT INTO gender VALUES
   (384583, 'Male');

CREATE TABLE contacts
   (contact_details         INT,
   staff_id                 INT REFERENCES staff(staff_id),
   PRIMARY KEY(contact_details, staff_id));

INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (022017456, 31);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (034737447, 31);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (02285756, 32);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (034735858, 32);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (034552097, 33);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (022867385, 33);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (021495939, 34);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (034993872, 35);
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES
   (027459278, 36);

COMMIT;
```

All the tables except the ones refering paper_code are working.

Errors are:

```
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (DAANDERSON.SYS_C00623423) violated - parent
key not found
```

For enrols:

```
   (paper_code     INT     REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
                                                 *
    ERROR at line 2:
   ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

For lecture_location

```
       (paper_code  INT REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
                                              *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

Been trying for a few hours and stil can't get to work. Any information appreciated!

Comment: if my suggestions worked, you should "accept" my answer (click the checkbox next to it).  Also, don't add a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your table `teaches`, you have:

```
FOREIGN KEY (paper_code, dept_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_code, dept_id));
```

So every (paper_code, dept_id) **must exist** as (paper_code, dept_id) in papers.

Your 2nd entry (241, 01) does not exist, nor does your fourth value (241, 03).
(others may be missing, I didn't check them all)

---

You're also not inserting `dept_id` values into `lecture_location`

---

You have a primary key value duplicated in `enrols`:

(160, 172384)

---

This part of `enrols`:

```
CREATE TABLE enrols
(paper_code         INT     REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
```

is invalid, since you must reference a unique foreign key - and the only unique key on papers is its primary key of (paper_code, dept_id)

---

Ditto for this part of `lecture_location`:

```
(paper_code      INT     REFERENCES papers(paper_code),
```

---

On the bright side, after doing the fixes above the schema actually builds: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ed2c2